# OpenLayers 3 : Problem with the tracker?

Tags: openlayers, gps

I try to make a tracker with OpenLayers. The localization point appears well but not in the right place.

[image]

```
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<img id="geolocation_marker" src="geolocation_marker.png" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4,
      maxZoom: 4,
      minZoom: 4,
    })
  });

var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
  projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
  tracking: true,
  trackingOptions: {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maximumAge: 2000  
  }
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
 image: new ol.style.Icon({
  anchor: [0.5, 100],
  anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
  anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
  opacity: 1.0,
  src: 'geolocation_marker.png'
 })
});

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature();   
var iconSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature]
});    
var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: iconSource,
  style : iconStyle
});    
map.addLayer(iconLayer); 

geolocation.on('change', function() {
  var pos = geolocation.getPosition();
  iconFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(pos));
  view.setCenter(pos);
  view.setZoom(4); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: what happens when you move so tracking point follows up to device's gps.

Comment: With this problem and your tip, my script works perfectly, but the positionning is still wrong??? Ol3 5.1.3 The result is the same with the sample of ol3? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Does the [official geolocation example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html) work for you? If not it might be something in your browser. Is it asking to allow sharing your location or something like that?

For me the following code works:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4,
      maxZoom: 4,
      minZoom: 4,
    })
  });

var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
  projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
  tracking: true,
  trackingOptions: {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maximumAge: 2000  
  }
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 6,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#3399CC'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature();   
var iconSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature]
});    
var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: iconSource,
  style : iconStyle
});    
map.addLayer(iconLayer); 

geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
  var pos = geolocation.getPosition();
  iconFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(pos));
  map.getView().fit(iconFeature.getGeometry());
  map.getView().setZoom(4); 
});
```

I just changed the style definition, because of the image and change it is now `'change:position'` and you couldn't reach the view with `map.getView()` it works.

You can try it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmYyaN?&editors=1010)